# Sql-alchemy Integrity error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have User model which is described as below:-

```
class User(db.Model, object):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

Now I have a registration form which is described as below:-

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), Length(max=50)])
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
```

NOW THE PROBLEM,

When I register/signup through web-app, id is automatically incremented and a new user is created. So I created user1 with id1 getting automatically assigned by sql-alchemy through registration form.

Now I use insert statement in database to insert a new user with a valid id. So I created user2 with id2 through insert statement in database.

If I try to create user3 through web-app, it shows **sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.**

Now again if I try to signup with user3, it creates a new user.

I tried using autoload to make flask know about recent id but it is not working.

Comment: You could set the id to explicitly increment like so: `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)`

Comment: It is not working by including autoincrement=True. It is incrementing if I try again after error shows up.

Comment: Did you apply the changes to your DB after adding `..., autoincrement=True`? That does not happen automatically, you have to migrate existing DBs somehow, i.e. alter your integer primary key column to a serial.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I think need to use sql-migrate and alembic to do so or restarting the flask server would be fine or should I drop entire table?

Comment: I've no experience with sql-migrate, but alembic's nice for handling a projects migrations. If you're just starting and don't have much data, then dropping and recreating is an easy approach.

Comment: I figured out the mistake. The insert statement which I used was "insert into users values (2,'user2','user2@gmail.com','sha256-asdadfg')". It works correctly when I use "insert into users(username,email,password) values ('user2','user2@gmail.com','sha256-asdadfg')"

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to query the maximum id from id column and increment it by 1 and assign it to the new user to prevent primary key collision.

```
max_id = session.query(User).order_by(User.id.desc()).first()
new_user = User(id=max_id+1, email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data, password=hashed_password)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Sequence to auto-increment your id.

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Sequence

id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Did you recreate the schema ? Be sure that the sequence was created.