# FLASK After commit causes odd IntegrityError violates unique constraint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**UPDATE / CLARIFICATION**

I confirmed that this strange behavior only occurs on the macOS machine, moving everything to a windows machine (using sqlite and doing a fresh init and migrate) doesn't cause the error... doing the same on my High Sierra box does cause the odd error.

Is anyone familiar with some known difference between sqlalchemy on Windows and macOS that might help?

---

Short version... I'm getting an integrity error (unique constraint) after I try to commit ANY entry to the DB, even if there are NO EXISTING entries at all in the table... why?

**DETAILS**

I've built a FLASK project (roughly based on the Miguel Grinberg Flask Maga Tutorial) using postgresql and sqlalchemy, the front-end has a page to register a user with a confirmation email (which works *fine*)...  to save time I've written a route (see below) which pre-loads a confirmed user to the Users database, this user is the **ONLY** user in the Users table and I only visit the route *ONE TIME*.

After a successful commit I get an *IntegrityError* "duplicate key value violates unique constraint". This route only adds **ONE** user to an existing **EMPTY** Users table. The data IS successfully saved to the DB, the user can log in, but an error gets thrown. I get a similar error (see below) but am focusing on this route as an example because it is shorter than other views I've written.

**EXAMPLE OF ROUTE CAUSING UNIQUE CONSTRAINT ERROR**

```
@main.route('/popme')
#@login_required
def popme():
    ## add user
    u1 = User()
    u1.email = 'user@domain.com'
    u1.username = 'someuser'
    u1.password_hash = 'REMOVED'
    u1.confirmed = '1'
    u1.role_id = 3
    u1.name = 'Some User'
    db.session.add(u1)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('User someuser can now login!')
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

*I only started getting this error after moving the entire project from a Windows machine to a MacOS machine. I'm running Python 3.6 in a virtual environment, this error occurs if I'm using sqlite3 or postgresql.*

I've written a much longer route which pre-fills in about 20 other tables successfully (does on commit() at the end, all data IS stored in the DB), however I get an IntegrityError "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" every time for a seemingly random entry. I've destroyed the DB, done an init, migrated... each time when the commit() is called a IntegrityError is thrown, each time on a different table, there is no apparent reasoning.

**BELOW IS USER MODEL**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

    def ping(self):
        self.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(self)

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def generate_confirmation_token(self, expiration=3600):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
        return s.dumps({'confirm': self.id})

    def confirm(self, token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('confirm') != self.id:
            return False
        self.confirmed = True
        db.session.add(self)
        return True

    def generate_reset_token(self, expiration=3600):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
        return s.dumps({'reset': self.id})

    def reset_password(self, token, new_password):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('reset') != self.id:
            return False
        self.password = new_password
        db.session.add(self)
        return True

    def generate_email_change_token(self, new_email, expiration=3600):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
        return s.dumps({'change_email': self.id, 'new_email': new_email})

    def change_email(self, token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('change_email') != self.id:
            return False
        new_email = data.get('new_email')
        if new_email is None:
            return False
        if self.query.filter_by(email=new_email).first() is not None:
            return False
        self.email = new_email
        db.session.add(self)
        return True

    def can(self, permissions):
        return self.role is not None and (self.role.permissions & permissions) == permissions

    def is_administrator(self):
        return self.can(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.role is None:
            if self.email == current_app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN']:
                self.role = Role.query.filter_by(permissions=0xff).first()
            if self.role is None:
                self.role = Role.query.filter_by(default=True).first()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

I've tried [Sql-alchemy Integrity error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758508/sql-alchemy-integrity-error) but its my understanding that sqlalchemy does auto-increment primary keys.

**UPDATED INTEGRITY ERROR**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_users_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(worldbmd@gmail.com) already exists.
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (email, username, password_hash, confirmed, role_id, name, last_seen) VALUES (%(email)s, %(username)s, %(password_hash)s, %(confirmed)s, %(role_id)s, %(name)s, %(last_seen)s) RETURNING users.id'] [parameters: {'email': 'user@domain.com', 'username': 'someuser', 'password_hash': 'REMOVED', 'confirmed': '1', 'role_id': 1, 'name': 'Some User', 'last_seen': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 17, 27, 13, 451593)}]
```

Comment: The error and user model do not compliment each other. As the error says the unique key violation it mean value is already present in the field. Have you checked for the same value being inserted before the commit?

Comment: I updated the error to the specific one caused by the code given. I am sure, there are no other entries in the User table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the sample problem on High Sierra!

Answer (score 0):

I also got into the same problem..as Joost said flask app runs twice. So we need to set it to run only once. We can achieve it by adding `use_reloader=False` like:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

or
we can directly set `debug=False`,

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

The integrity error is caused by trying to add a blister to the blisters table with a non unique property. I think your model looks something like this:

```
class Blister(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blisters'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    notes= db.Column(db.String(64))
    cost= db.Column(db.Float)
```

And you're trying to add a blister with a name `Small round dome` which is already in the blisters table in the database, therefore causing the Integrity Error.

Comment: Thanks however, I add three **unique** blisters into an EMPTY table actually, however the error still exists.  My model (not shown here) actually does have a unique requirement on the name field.

Comment: Do you add them when visiting a route, or when booting up the app? When they are added as soon as you hit `flask run` in the command line, they might be added twice, because of the way a flask app starts.

Comment: If I add them when visiting the route all works as expected, no error. When I use the generated code I get the error... Running the exact same thing (sans changing the DB location) on a Windows box does not give the error. Can you elaborate what you mean about "the way a flask app starts" please? I'm using a  manager via flask-script, I run `manage.py run server` and the app runs fine until I try to add and DB entries on the mac. Thanks